# Doubly Linked List C++. Insert After Function not Working

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have written an insertAfter function but it is not working
Please help!!!

The Function is not working. When I run it the to test fails.

```
  template <class T>
  void LinkedList<T>::insertAfter(T toInsert, T afterWhat)
 {
  ListItem<T> *Node = (ListItem<T>*)malloc(sizeof(ListItem<T>));
     Node->value = toInsert;
     Node->next = NULL;
     Node->prev = NULL;
    if(head == NULL){
    return;
    }
    ListItem<T> *temp = head;
    while(temp->value != afterWhat && temp->next != NULL){
    temp = temp->next;
    }

temp->next->prev = Node;
temp->next = Node;
Node->prev = temp;
Node->next = temp->next;
}
```

Comment: If you exit the loop due to `temp->next == NULL`, then `temp->next->prev = Node;`, etc.. invoke *Undefined Behavior* and likely a SegFault. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: I added **temp != NULL** too but stilll not working.@da

Comment: Please give a more detailed diagnostic than "not working". Did you inspect the resulting data structure in the debugger? Which invariants were broken? What did you expect? What do you observe?

Comment: Is (head == NULL) an error or just an indication that the list is empty? If head is the first entry (as seen in the while loop), then head must be filled in when it is NULL. If the new entry can only be inserted when afterWhat is found, then an extra check is needed to fail when it is not found.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The order of assigning next and prev nodes is wrong

```
temp->next->prev = Node;
temp->next = Node;
Node->prev = temp;
Node->next = temp->next;
```

because in the second line you have temp->next=Node then Node->next=temp->next with the result that Node->next=Node. Fix it like this

```
temp->next->prev = Node;
Node->prev = temp;
Node->next = temp->next;
temp->next = Node;// changed the position of this statement
```